# iCloud photo library causing duplicate photos

Tags: icloud

Ever since I started using iCloud photo library I am getting duplicates in photo on iMac OS X El Capitan. Also, all photos that went into the iCloud photo library  uploaded on iPhone too.

What am I doing wrong? I don't want all photos on iPhone and certainly don't need duplicates in photo.

Answer (score 1):

iCloud doesn't duplicate the photos, it just stores them in iCloud.

The purpose of iCloud Photo Library is to allow you to access your photos on all your devices. If you don't want your photos on your iPhone, don't use iCloud Photo Library.

Comment: Somehow since i started the iCloud photo library I have duplicates of many photos. Not sure if this is happening because of the original upload to the library or my settings on the iMac or phone are causing this issue.